# IAP Autorenenewable subscription purchase returns status as failed in observer but says successful in the pop up

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

```
extension IAPService:SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions{

        print(transaction.transactionState.status(),transaction.payment.productIdentifier)

        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing :break
        case .purchased :         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "purchased"), object: self)



            receiptValidation()

        default :queue.finishTransaction(transaction)


        }
    }
}
}
```

When I try purchasing a subscription it works fine sometimes but then after a period it says failed in status log. But still the pop up from apple says purchase successful you are all set. Is there some kind of limit we can use a sandbox account buy and test the app?

Comment: Do you finish the transaction after you validate the receipt?

Comment: i do the validation once it returns purchase status